# Delete Rows a day after the date has passed

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, delete-row

I am still fairly new at script writing and am trying a write a script that deletes a row one day after the date which is in column L. The data is in range A133 to L117. I've gotten the code below from several different [sources][1] but it has several issues. The first being that I get the error message "cannot read property 'getRange' of Null, on line 3 even though I've describe the array I want it to pull data from.

The second issue is with the below code - I'm not sure it's right, and would appreciate any help getting it to work for my current need. Here is the code.

```
function DeleteOldEntries() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet 1");
var values = sheet.getRange(2,1,5,12);

var currentDate = new Date();//today

for (i=lastrow;i>=3;i--) {
var tempDate = values[i-1][2];// arrays are 0 indexed so row1 = values[0] and col3 = [2]
if ((tempDate!=NaN) && (tempDate <= currentDate))
{
  sheet.deleteRow(i);
}//closes if
}//closes for loop
}//closes function
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `var values = sheet.getRange(2,1,5,12).getValues();`  and `tempDate.valueOf() <= currentDate.valueOf()`

Comment: @TheWizEd thanks for the tips. I changed my sheet name to "Sheet1" and the code ran until line 3 again where it said "The parameters (number,number,number,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getDataRange. I've modified the values within it several times but am still getting the same result

Comment: `.getDataRange()` retrieves a blanket range with dimensions where data is present. You cannot specify columns and rows in that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **For your first issue:**

> The first being that I get the error message "cannot read property 'getRange' of Null, on line 3 even though I've describe the array I want it to pull data from.

This error means your `sheet` variable is incorrect.

This could mean your sheet name is incorrect, or that there is no active spreadsheet. If you are running this in a script file not attached to a Sheets file, you will need to use `SpreadsheetApp.openById()` or `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl()` in place of `SpreadsheetApp.getActive()`.

On a side note, you are also not retrieving any values in `values`, rather, just declaring a range.

```
// var values = sheet.getRange(2,1,5,12);
var values = sheet.getRange(2,1,5,12).getValues();
```

### **For your second issue:**

Comparing dates is not so cut and dry.

A possible solution **to remove all rows that are not from today**, would be to declare `currentDate` as a string with formatting similar to what you are using in your date columns use. As an example, if you're sheet dates look like (`May-06 2022`):

```
const values = sheet.getRange(2,1,5,12).getDisplayValues();

const currentDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), `YOUR_TIMEZONE`, `MMM-dd YYY`)
```

You can then remove all rows in your sheet that's date does not match the current date, using the for loop you wrote:

```
  for (let i = lastrow; i > 2; i--) {
    if (values[i-1][2] !== currentDate) {
      sheet.deleteRow(i)
    }
  }
```

If you are looking to remove dates that are **specifically** 1 day old, you will have to use date comparison, which can be accomplished a few ways.

Here's one solution:

```
const currentDate = new Date();

for (let i = lastrow; i > 2; i--) {
  if (currentDate.getDate()-1 === values[i-1][2].getDate()) {
    sheet.deleteRow(i)
  }
}
```

### **Solutions**

**Date as String Method:**

```
function DeleteOldEntries() {

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet 1");
  const values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();

  const currentDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "YOUR_TIMEZONE", "m/d/yyyy");

  for (let i = values.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (values[i][11] !== currentDate) {
      sheet.deleteRow(i+2)
    }
  }

}
```

**Date Comparison:** (Strictly one day ago)

```
function DeleteOldEntries() {

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet 1");
  const values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  const currentDate = new Date();

  for (let i = values.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (currentDate.getDate()-1 === values[i][11].getDate()) {
      sheet.deleteRow(i+2);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi @NEWAZA. Thank you for your comments. My sheet was actually incorrectly identified. There is no space between sheet and 1. However, I still get an error that The parameters (number,number,number,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getDataRange. Could this be because my values are in A113 to L117?

Comment: Hey @Josanon, I commented your original post that you cannot specify columns and rows in `.getDataRange()`; based on how your code is structured in your post and in my reply, you should use `.getRange()`.

Comment: I also get a comment that my last row is undefined. Also, does the fact that my dates are in column L matter in the code?

Comment: Hi @NEWAZA, you are correct, thank you. I hadn't seen that and have now updated the change. What I get now is that "last row" is undefined.

Comment: Try defining it as `const lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();` below your `values` variable. And yes, if your dates are in Column L, you will need to change your `if` statements to look at `values[i-1][11]`.

Comment: I've included the constant. now the issue I run into is on this line if (currentDate.getDate()-1 === values[i-1][11].getDate()) { and the error message is "cannot read property '11' of undefined, which makes me think that it still may not think that row is undefined

Comment: @Josanon I've updated the solution code for you

Comment: I've ran the code and it gets executed. But then I got to my sheet and nothing has happened. I should mention that the dates are formatted like so m/d/yyyy, and are not today's dates. For example, COL L has the dates 4/11/2022. So technically, if I ran the code, given that it's been more than one day after the date, they should all be deleted right ? And if I wanted to delete x days after. I should just put '-x'? Also, why did you add i+2?

Comment: Which solution are you using? ... `deleteRow(i+2)` is deleting the row of the current index (i) + our starting row of the range (2).

Comment: Sorry, I am using the second solution, the one with the date comparison

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244557/discussion-between-josanon-and-newaza).

Comment: Code is updated and solution has been found.